# How to define the amount of the error bar in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to graphic with error bars in vba excel and I my code works just fine. Only instead of putting the error bars with the data in the range I have defined it puts error bars with a fixed value and I can not figure out why.

```
Sub meanSD()


Dim sumsht As Worksheet
Set sumsht = Worksheets("Summary")
Dim chtobj As ChartObject
Set chtobj = sumsht.ChartObjects.Add(70, 700, 600, 300)
Dim rngAmount As Range
Set rngAmount = sumsht.Range(Cells(2, 51), Cells(41, 51))

With chtobj.Chart
  .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
  .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Summary!$B$50:$AO$50")
  .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Summary!$A$1"
  .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Summary!$B$3:$AO$4"
  .FullSeriesCollection(1).HasErrorBars = True
  .FullSeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Select
  .FullSeriesCollection(1).ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlErrorBarIncludeBoth, Type:=xlErrorBarTypeCustom, Amount:=rngAmount, MinusValues:=rngAmount
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with an array of Variant values, or a Range object. Keep in mind that if you use a Range, the value of the error bars will update whenever the value of those cells changes.

## Example using Arrays

For my case, I did not want to write out the data in any cells, so I used arrays:

### Create and fill these arrays

I did not test what happens if you put negative values in either of these arrays.

```
Dim posYError() As Variant
Dim negYError() As Variant

Dim numberOfDataPoints As Integer
numberOfDataPoints = 20

ReDim posYError(0 To numberOfDataPoints)
ReDim negYError(0 To numberOfDataPoints)

'Fill them with the data you want
For m = 0 To numberOfDataPoints
    posYError(m) = m * 0.3
    negYError(m) = m * 0.6  'These are still positive
Next m
```

### Actually set the Error Bars

You must specify an array for both positive and negative error bars when using *xlErrorBarTypeCustom*, failure to do so will generate an error (I just spent like three hours figuring this out, trust me).

```
Dim oSerie As series
Set oSerie = oChart.SeriesCollection(1)

'Enable the Error Bars
oSerie.HasErrorBars = True
oSerie.ErrorBars.EndStyle = xlCap

'Specify the Error Bar Values
Call oSerie.ErrorBar(xlX, xlErrorBarIncludeNone, xlErrorBarTypeFixedValue, 0)
Call oSerie.ErrorBar(xlY, xlErrorBarIncludeBoth, xlErrorBarTypeCustom, posYError, negYError)
```

#### Further Notes

Excel Verson (in general, the current one for Windows 10):
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20698) 32-bit

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is a VBA problem, unless there is a requirement that is missing.

In Excel 2007:

- Select the Chart
- Select Layout
- Select Error Bars
- Select More Error Bars Options
- Specify the format for Error Bars
- Select "Custom" and then enter the range for positive and negative values.

Also, a trend here on SE is to recommend that you avoid use of "Select" in your VBA.  So, the statement:  `.FullseriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Select`  is extraneous.